# Automated Accessibility Testing/Screenreader Emulators

Tags: asp.net, accessibility

Apart from the web accessibility toolbar for IE and the WAVE tool. Does anyone know of any other tools to assist in web accessibility testing.

I'm also looking for a screen reader emulator.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Firefox plug-in screenreader emulator called [Fangs](http://www.standards-schmandards.com/projects/fangs/).  It doesn't actually read the text and provide audio like JAWS but, it does show the text of how a screenreader would read it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [standards-schmandards.com](http://www.standards-schmandards.com/exhibits/fangs/fangs-sample.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [Illinois Center for Information Technology and Web Accessibility](http://www.cita.uiuc.edu/) makes a great [Firefox plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5809) called the Functional Web Accessibility Evaluator (FAE). It analyzes your HTML and finds potential accessibility problems. Coverage includes navigational elements (titles, headings, links, tables, etc.), text equivalents, scripting and even color contrast analysis.

They also have a beta version with [ARIA support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria), and are hoping to soon start development on a Firebug extension.

Overall a very cool plug-in to add to your toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

A screenreader emulator would be... a screenreader. Download [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) and use the trial version.

Comment: There are just emulators (see my answer) that don't provide the actual audio - just text of how a screenreader would read it.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that existed. But I'd argue that it's a poor substitute for testing with a screenreader, since things like access keys, AJAX and other interactions change how the user experiences the page. It'd be like testing the usability of a webpage by looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Oh, it's absolutely a poor substitute but, it can give you a good idea of what a screenreader will do once a JAWS trial runs out and you can't spend $900 on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the jaws demo will run in 40 minute mode indefinitly but since I"m blind I had to buy the full version. For a list of screen readers as well as my opinions and experiences on them see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796887/screen-readers-for-testing-website-accessibility)