# Bearing in mind accessibility, is it kosher to dynamically group LIs into DIVs?

Tags: javascript, dom, accessibility

Hi
To make convenient some animation, my strategy for a client-side script involves grouping list items into DIVs. It seems that having anything other than LIs as the children of OL or UL elements does validate. However, I'd be doing this in script, so no validation issue (for what that's worth!).

But might this cause a problem with screen readers and so on? 
Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: can you clarify with an example. do you mean <UL><LI><DIV/><DIV/></LI></UL>. Why would you worry about this? surely there are DIVs all over the place elsewhere and screenreaders are fine with them

Comment: @Simon I agree, given more information on what you are trying to do we would be able to give you a much better answer. As it is, my answer is highly generalized because I do not know what you are trying to accomplish by inserting a div into a ul.

Comment: +1 because you care about accessibility, even if it's your boss or protocol who is enforcing it, it should be at the very least highly encouraged.

Comment: @Moses and @Simon_Weaver Sorry guys, could have been clearer, I mean for example: `<ul><div><li>list item</li></div></ul>`. The purpose is to group some number of list items to make animation more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One way to find out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796887/screen-readers-for-testing-website-accessibility) I don't think there would be too much trouble, but the only way to know is to test it. Javascript's interaction with screen readers [is a complex subject](http://northtemple.com/2008/10/07/javascript-and-screen-readers), so I'm hesitant to make any firm judgments. [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) seems like a good place to start. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd normally steer clear of invalid markup, but I can't think of a better way to group things in the way you want to. Perhaps consider whether a single list is the best markup to use rather than multiple lists or some other set of constructs. Since you are needing to group list items in this way, it seems likely that there's a semantic reason for grouping them in markup as well.

As it goes, if browsers cope with the invalid markup in question, it is likely to work in screen readers and the like as well. As CrazyJugglerDrummer says, it's best to test it. However, you never know when that invalid markup is going to start causing problems in future software releases.

Answer (score 0):

First off, screen readers and JavaScript do not have the best track record of compatibility. (Correct me if I'm wrong, I am no expert on usability) From what I have come to understand, screen readers typically read a static version of your page, and refresh it at seemingly random times irregardless of what dynamic changes have occured through JavaScript. This was my last experience with screen readers, but that was 3 years ago so things may have changed for the better.

To give an example, if your dynamic list is in fact an accordion that expands and contracts, you cannot with any degree of certainty know if a screen reader will display the text being shown (even if the JavaScript made the text visible to the screen).

Before I would start worrying about problems your script might cause for screen readers, *I would instead focus on your overall accessibility of the site structure* (HTML+CSS). Are you making integral elements to your page keyboard focusable? Are you following [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) guidelines? Are you using the correct technique to hide content (situation dependent) `display:none`, `left:-9999px`, or `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: Things have moved on since those days. For example, JAWS 7.1 and later provide JavaScript developers with [a mechanism for refreshing the screen reader's "virtual buffer"](http://juicystudio.com/article/improving-ajax-applications-for-jaws-users.php) of pages.